# Most difficult puzzles for chess engines

Tags: engines, puzzles

I know this type of question has been asked a few times but each of the puzzles in the answers are solved by engines. For example Plaskett’s puzzle and other common ones such as Mitrofanov deflection and Mario Matous’ mate in 13 can be seen by matefinders easily. Are there any puzzles that truly stump engines?

Comment: The truth is, every puzzle is solvable by computer.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, swindles and those sort of puzzles stump engines because practically the best chance of winning is variation A, but the computer prefers variation B because it has a different calculation system to us. Those are usually the hardest for computers and they usually get them wrong, even if it is technically correct.

Comment: I found this interesting but the answer would be more compelling if it added a few example positions.

Comment: Marshall's swindles is an example but the course on chessable has many examples.